# Union of two matrices in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, union

Is it posible to make de union between two matrices in python? I mean to have in one matrix all the elements from other two matrices without reapiting any of them. 
For example, if we have:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

B = [[5,6],[7,8]]
```

The union would be `C = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]`

There is a numpy command for arrays: `np.union1d` but I cannot find any for matrices. I just have found `np.concatenate` and `np.vstack` but they write twice the repeated elements.

Comment: It's not a "proper" union, but you can work the result out with a simple list-loop: `C = A + [ x for x in B if x not in A ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you can achieve using [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on the [concated](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) result of A and B, as below

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
B = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
np.unique(np.concatenate([A, B]), axis=0)
```

outputs

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

or a bit more [concise stacking](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) would be `np.unique(np.r_[A,B], axis=0)`